# quasar: yarn installed old version

Tags: quasar, yarn-v2

I tried the quick start quasar, but after installation quasar dev doesn't work.

I did following:

```
yarn --version
yarn install v1.22.5

yarn create quasar
cd project
quasar dev
```

result is:

Error Unknown command "dev"
Running @quasar/cli v1.1.3

How can I use newest quasar/cli version?

package.json:

> ```
>   "name": "quasar-project",
>   "version": "0.0.1",
>   "description": "A Quasar Project",
>   "productName": "Quasar App",
>   "author": "test@test.de",
>   "private": true,
>   "scripts": {
>     "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
>     "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,vue,scss,html,md,json}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
>     "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
>     "dev": "quasar dev",
>     "build": "quasar build"
>   },
>   "dependencies": {
>     "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.4",
>     "quasar": "^2.6.0",
>     "vue": "^3.0.0",
>     "vue-router": "^4.0.0"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "eslint": "^8.10.0",
>     "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
>     "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
>     "prettier": "^2.5.1",
>     "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.3.0",
>     "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
>     "postcss": "^8.4.14"
>   },
>   "engines": {
>     "node": "^18 || ^16 || ^14.19",
>     "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
>     "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
>   }
> ```

I overread an error message:

yarn FAILED...

```
 Quasar • ⚠️  Could not auto install dependencies. Probably a temporary npm registry issue?

To get started:

  cd quasar-project
  yarn #or: npm install
  yarn lint --fix # or: npm run lint -- --fix
  quasar dev # or: yarn quasar dev # or: npx quasar dev
```

but trying this:

```
error quasar-project@0.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^18 || ^16 || ^14.19". Got "12.22.9"
```

Comment: Please share the `package.json` file. It helps us to figure your dependencies and scripts out.

Answer (score 0):

update your node.js version to >=14
https://quasar.dev/start/quick-start#prerequisites